# What can I do about sudden serial port disconnects with open file handles?

Tags: c++, winapi, serial-communication

How can I close the serial port without getting invalid handle errors in Visual Studio? There doesn't seem to be a way to close them. The app almost works flawlessly as a release exe but it becomes impossible to work with when debugging as I have to repeatedly close the error messages.

Comment: if you get  invalid handle error - this mean you already close handle or pass invalid value

Comment: How about registering for a callback if the serial device is disconnected https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerdevicenotificationw  Using `DBT_DEVTYP_PORT` _"Port device (serial or parallel)."_

Comment: @RichardCritten even if device disconnected/removed - handle not become invalid and will be no errors *invalid handle*

Comment: @RbMm can you explain that a bit more clearer, I don't understand your last comment

Comment: `CloseHandle` doesn't display an error message on failure. It's the library you are using or have written that can. It's probably using some variation of `assert`. If it is using one of the `_ASSERT` macros provided by Microsoft's CRT you can control the behavior through [_CrtSetReportMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/crtsetreportmode). Setting `_CRTDBG_MODE_DEBUG` will display failed assertions in the debugger's output window instead of showing a dialog.

Comment: @Salty which api and what error returned ?

Comment: @IInspectable - `NtClose` (as result and `CloseHandle`) raise exception *0xC0000008: An invalid handle was specified.* if debugger attached to process

Comment: @RbMm I half fixed my sloppy logic so my program closes handles only on valid open handles and I get no more invalid handle errors but now the problem is I think I am leaking open handles. Visual Studio sometimes takes a much longer time to close the app and now I can't even run it, I get LINK errors when compiling. I have to copy the project to get it to work again. How can I check if i'm leaking open handles?

Comment: Have the type system help you out. [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) with a custom `Deleter` ensures that you do not leak resources.